# How can I arrange vectors of Zeros and Ones in Python, in an order on which the vectors with ones on the last index stay on the bottom?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

Is there an efficient way to re-organize this vector list in Python:

```
[
  [0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0,1,0],
  [0,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [0,0,1,0,1,1]
]
```

in a way that the ones that have `...,1]` on the last index stay on the bottom, followed by the vectors that have the sequence `...,1,0]` on the last indexes, and them `...,1,0,0]`, and so on...

```
[
  [0,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0,0,0],

  [0,0,1,0,1,0],

  [0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,0,1,0,1,1]
]
```

The inner order actually does not matter.

Comment: Search on "python sort tutorial".  You want to sort the list items, using a key of `item[-1]`, the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by the reversed element, so it compares the sub lists from the end of lists; In ascending order, lists with zeros will come before lists with ones with elements at the end of lists having higher priority:

```
lst = [
  [0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0,1,0],
  [0,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [0,0,1,0,1,1]
]

sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[::-1])

#[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Psidom, I did not realize I could use the key parameter this way. This is noticeable much faster than iterating for each element position over the vectors appending to a new structure.